# What is the difference between parseInt() and Number()?

Tags: javascript, performance

How do [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) behave differently when converting strings to numbers?

Comment: I think a closer comparison would be `parseFloat` vs `Number` since all numbers are 64-bit floats. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12227594/4294399

Answer (score 610, accepted):

Well, they are *semantically different*, the [`Number` constructor called as a function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1) performs *type conversion* and [`parseInt`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.2) performs *parsing*, e.g.:

```
// parsing:
parseInt("20px");       // 20
parseInt("10100", 2);   // 20
parseInt("2e1");        // 2

// type conversion
Number("20px");       // NaN
Number("2e1");        // 20, exponential notation
```

Also `parseInt` will ignore trailing characters that don't correspond with any digit of the currently used base.

The `Number` constructor doesn't detect implicit octals, but can detect the explicit octal notation:

```
Number("010");         // 10
Number("0o10")         // 8, explicit octal

parseInt("010");       // 8, implicit octal
parseInt("010", 10);   // 10, decimal radix used
```

And it can handle numbers in hexadecimal notation, just like `parseInt`:

```
Number("0xF");   // 15
parseInt("0xF"); //15
```

In addition, a widely used construct to perform Numeric type conversion, is the [Unary `+` Operator (p. 72)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), it is equivalent to using the `Number` constructor as a function:

```
+"2e1";   // 20
+"0xF";   // 15
+"010";   // 10
```

Comment: Interesting, does parseInt ignore any characters trailing the number? Because in my case I would prefer getting a NaN instead of the 20 when converting.

Comment: Yes it does. Sounds like you definitely want Number()

Comment: Okay, so I guess I will go with Number() but thanks a lot for clearing up this point and all these examples! :-)

Comment: @Mark, you're welcome, I'm glad to help, as I pointed at the end of the answer, you can use either `Number` or the unary plus operator, I like the operator for its shortness. @Gareth thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Thank you for this.  This is the first time I've seen NaN.  It may be helpful for some folks to know that NaN is tested with the function isNaN ( value ).  Just using "if ( value == NaN )", for example, won't work.

Comment: There is an other feature: `var foo = { valueOf: function() { return 5 } }; Number(foo) === +foo === 5; parseInt(foo) !== parseInt(foo) // NaN`

Comment: But value !== value  && typeof value === number  could be used to test if the  value is NaN . NaN sucks

Comment: `Number()` does deal with octals much like hex and binary: `Number('0o10') == 8`

Comment: `parseInt("010")` returns `10` in Chrome

Comment: Note that the behavior of parsing a number with leading 0 in octal base was changed in **ES3**, not ES5. Compare section 15.1.2.2 of [ES2](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%202nd%20edition,%20August%201998.pdf) and [ES3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) for the details.

Comment: parseInt() also gives the option to specify the base via the optional radix argument: `parseInt("071", 10);  // 71` vs `parseInt("071", 8);  // 57`. Especially useful for numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: `parseInt("010")` also returns `10` in Firefox and Node.js

Answer (score 34):

```
typeof parseInt("123") => number
typeof Number("123") => number
typeof new Number("123") => object (Number primitive wrapper object)
```

first two will give you better performance as it returns a primitive instead of an object.

Comment: Ah I see Number( someString ) means I pass in a string to its constructor and get an object in return.

Comment: `new Number()` is different to `Number()`. `typeof Number("123") => number`

Comment: I think this is one of the most important point to take note from performance point of view, as objects consume much more memory and processing time. Nice discussion from you both, letronje and Gareth.

Comment: Also `new Number("1") != new Number("1")`. **NEVER USE `new Number`**. Never never never never. `Number("1")`, on the other hand, is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Kragen, it'd be much more beneficial to the community if you explained WHY you shouldn't use "new Number" -- instead of just typing "never" 5 times...

Comment: @ken Very old comment but for future visitors I imagine its because exactly the reason they mentioned to begin with. I parse two numbers `let x = new Number("2"); let y = new Number("2");` and then later on do an equality check for whatever reason, `if (x == y) { doSomething(); }` logically `doSomething` should be called. But it wont. Also if you were to parse only one number `let x = new Number("2");` then `x === 2` would be false. That is a clear reason why you should not use `new Number`

Comment: @TomC You're seeing the result of an edited comment (that's what the pencil icon following the comment denotes); previously there was zero explanation, just strong admonition.

Answer (score 27):

One minor difference is what they convert of `undefined` or `null`,

```
Number() Or Number(null) Or Number('') // returns 0
```

while

```
parseInt() Or parseInt(null) // returns NaN
```

Comment: That’s because _ToNumber_ (**null**) is [specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) to return `0`. [`parseInt`, however expects _strings_](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix), so `null` and `undefined` are coerced to the strings `"null"` or `"undefined"`, respectively, first, which don’t start with digits. `Number(undefined)` is `NaN`, not `0`, which is a [special step of the `Number(`…`)` algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value). At any rate, the question asked about “when converting strings to numbers”, not about these special cases.

Answer (score 18):

### Summary:

`parseInt()`:

- Takes a string as a first argument, the radix (An integer which is the base of a numeral system e.g. decimal 10 or binary 2) as a second argument
- The function returns a integer number, if the first character cannot be converted to a number `NaN` will be returned.
- If the `parseInt()` function encounters a non numerical value, it will cut off the rest of input string and only parse the part until the non numerical value.
- If the radix is `undefined` or 0, JS will assume the following:

  - If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal), the remainder of the string is parsed into a number.
  - If the input value begins with a 0 the radix can be either 8 (octal) or 10 (decimal). Which radix is chosen is depending on JS engine implementation. `ES5` specifies that 10 should be used then. However, this is not supported by all browsers, **therefore always specify radix if your numbers can begin with a 0.**
  - If the input value begins with any number, the radix will be 10

`Number()`:

- The `Number()` constructor can convert any argument input into a number. If the `Number()` constructor cannot convert the input into a number, `NaN` will be returned.
- The `Number()` constructor can also handle hexadecimal number, they have to start with `0x`.

### Example:

```js
console.log(parseInt('0xF', 16));  // 15

// z is no number, it will only evaluate 0xF, therefore 15 is logged
console.log(parseInt('0xFz123', 16));

// because the radix is 10, A is considered a letter not a number (like in Hexadecimal)
// Therefore, A will be cut off the string and 10 is logged
console.log(parseInt('10A', 10));  // 10

// first character isnot a number, therefore parseInt will return NaN
console.log(parseInt('a1213', 10));


console.log('\n');


// start with 0X, therefore Number will interpret it as a hexadecimal value
console.log(Number('0x11'));

// Cannot be converted to a number, NaN will be returned, notice that
// the number constructor will not cut off a non number part like parseInt does
console.log(Number('123A'));

// scientific notation is allowed
console.log(Number('152e-1'));  // 15.21
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are looking for performance then probably best results you'll get with bitwise right shift `"10">>0`. Also multiply (`"10" * 1`) or not not (`~~"10"`). All of them are much faster of `Number` and `parseInt`.
They even have "feature" returning 0 for not number argument.
Here are [Performance tests](http://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/3).

Comment: The speed of the various approaches appears to change with browser revisions over time. The linked test also has changed, and the latest version as of this comment is here - http://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/39 -  fortunately the site contains previous versions of the test as well

Comment: @bobo, sure. Out of curiosity checked with chrome - `Number` and `parseInt` still slower 99% than the rest. Plus to me they are less attractive visually too :-)

Comment: @Saulius less visually attractive, but much more Google-able :)

Comment: Always prefer code clarity over "useless" optimizations. For most use cases `parseInt` or `Number` are more preferable. If you are programming a N64 emulator with millions of conversions per seconds, you might consider those tricks.

Comment: Question is about behavior, discussion of performance is off-topic.

Comment: Note that this can't be used for large integers -- specifically integers that don't fit in a signed 32-bit integer -- because in JavaScript, bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits, rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers. Hence `(2**31).toString() >> 0` will overflow to `-2147483648`. You can use `>>>` instead of `>>` to have JavaScript treat the operand as an *unsigned* 32-bit integer, but then any numbers larger than `2**32 - 1` will also overflow.

Comment: I tried it today and found that `Number` was ahead of bitwise and `*1`, `~~"10"` had a way lower score for me.

Answer (score 14):

I found two links of performance compare among several ways of converting `string` to `int`.

```js
    parseInt(str,10)    
    parseFloat(str)
    str << 0
    +str
    str*1 
    str-0
    Number(str)
```

[image]
http://jsben.ch/#/zGJHM

[image]
[image]
http://phrogz.net/js/string_to_number.html

Answer (score 8):

`parseInt()` -> Parses a number to specified redix.

`Number()`-> Converts the specified value to its numeric equivalent or NaN if it fails to do so.

Hence for converting some non-numeric value to number we should always use Number() function.

eg.

```
Number("")//0
parseInt("")//NaN

Number("123")//123
parseInt("123")//123

Number("123ac") //NaN,as it is a non numeric string
parsInt("123ac") //123,it parse decimal number outof string

Number(true)//1
parseInt(true) //NaN
```

There are various corner case to `parseInt()` functions as it does redix conversion, hence we should avoid using parseInt() function for coersion purposes.

Now, to check weather the provided value is Numeric or not,we should use native`isNaN()` function

Comment: parseInt() only parses a number out of a string that contains letters if the number part comes first

Comment: "it parse decimal number" parseInt() parses the integer, leaves the decimal part, for example parseInt('1.1') returns 1

Answer (score 8):

It's a good idea to stay away from parseInt and use Number and Math.round unless you need hex or octal. Both can use strings. Why stay away from it?

```
parseInt(0.001, 10)
0

parseInt(-0.0000000001, 10)
-1

parseInt(0.0000000001, 10)
1

parseInt(4000000000000000000000, 10)
4
```

It completely butchers really large or really small numbers. Oddly enough it works normally if these inputs are a string.

```
parseInt("-0.0000000001", 10)
0

parseInt("0.0000000001", 10)
0

parseInt("4000000000000000000000", 10)
4e+21
```

Instead of risking hard to find bugs with this and the other gotchas people mentioned, I would just avoid `parseInt` unless you need to parse something other than base 10. `Number`, `Math.round`, `Math.floor`, and `.toFixed(0)` can all do the same things `parseInt` can be used for without having these types of bugs.

If you really want or need to use parseInt for some of it's other qualities, never use it to convert floats to ints.

Comment: Wow, this is really useful! Bugs from parseInt could be hard to find indeed. Your answer deserves many more upvotes!

Comment: That’s because `parseInt` _expects_ strings. Any non-string is first coerced to a string. Since `4000000000000000000000` is not a safe integer, its string representation is `4e+21`, and `parseInt`’s left-to-right parsing stops before the non-digit `e`. Using `parseInt` with numeric arguments or to round a number is a misuse.

Comment: The MDN reference for `parseInt` should be checked by anyone who thinks this answer deserves an upvote. The `parseInt` function does not accept a number. It's for parsing strings. If you use JavaScript, it will coerce the number into a string before the function receives the argument (which is what causes the rounding) and if you use TypeScript it won't even compile because it's wrong. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 7):

I always use parseInt, but beware of leading zeroes that will force it into *octal* mode.

Comment: I think it's always a good idea to supply a radix to `parseInt(value, radix)` that way you don't have accidental *octal mode* conversions, etc.

Comment: Leading zeroes *will* force it into octal mode in ECMAScript 3. ECMAScript 5 will parse it to `0`, even in non-strict mode. But this has been fixed and now leading zeroes are just ignored, so `parseInt("070")` would become `70`.

Comment: You should be using a linter as well that will warn you to provide a radix value into `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt converts to a integer number, that is, it strips decimals. Number does not convert to integer.

Comment: Just for fun it seems that e.g. `Number("10.0")` does return `10`, but `Number("10.1")` returns `10.1`. So, that's a fun special case to watch out for.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to get the result is to use the ~ operator

For most circumstances

```
~~someThing === parseInt(something)
```

but ~~ will return zero for strings that parseInt will accept with trailing other characters or with the number base spec  (eg hex) and will also return zero when parseInt returns NaN.  Another difference is that ~~ if given a bigint returns a bigint to which you can add another bigint whereas parseInt returns an ordinary floating point number (yes really - it gives exactly the same value as parseFloat)  if the bigint is large

However for most circumstances ~~ is 30% faster than parseInt.  It is only slower by 10% when something is a floating point represented as a string.

So if the more restricted scope of ~~ fits your need then save the computer time and give yourself less to type