# Javascript Input Numbers

Tags: javascript

How do you take 2 numbers from the User with window.prompt and add them up without concatenating?

What I thought was:

```
var temp = window.prompt("Number1")
var temp2 = window.prompt("Number2")
var answer = temp + temp2;
document.write(answer);
```

but it only concatenates not adds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert the values to Number, there are plenty of ways to do it:

```
var test1 = +window.prompt("Number1"); // unary plus operator
var test2 = Number(window.prompt("Number2")); // Number constructor
var test3 = parseInt(window.prompt("Number3"), 10); // an integer? parseInt
var test4 = parseFloat(window.prompt("Number4")); // parseFloat
```

Comment: Note: To know the differences between the unary plus operator, the `Number` constructor called as a function and `parseInt`/`parseFloat` check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number/4090577#4090577)

Comment: Note 2: Using *no-op* mathematical operations such as `foo * 1;` or `foo - 0` are slightly equivalent to use the unary plus operator or the `Number` constructor called as a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = parseInt(temp) + parseInt(temp2);
```

is what you're looking for

More information on parseInt: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Please, don't link to w3schools, that's is by far the worse place one can go to. Link to MDC instead:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly convert them to numbers:

```
var answer = Number(temp) + Number(temp2);
```

A somewhat faster alternative is:

```
var answer = (temp - 0) + (temp2 - 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

by default, text from window.prompt is interpreted as string so the + operator concatinates them, you need to parse the values to integers using `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your input is a string (text) and you have to convert it to a number.

You can do that with the `parseInt()` function or by mixing it with another number.

Examples:

```
var temp = window.prompt("Number1") * 1;
var temp = parseInt(window.prompt("Number2");
```