# Javascript Comparison value === +value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript: plus symbol before variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable)
>   [obj.length === +obj.length in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188998/obj-length-obj-length-in-javascript)

While looking at the [source of underscore.js](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) I came across this line (#79)

```
//some stuff
} else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
//do stuff
```

I'm not 100% certain of whats going on here, can anyone explain the 
purpose of the '+' before the obj.length value?? Would the comparison
be identical if it just read:

```
} else if (obj.length === obj.length) {
```

The same type of comparison is made multiple times in underscore.js, so 
I'm fairly certain it's not a typo.

If anyone could point me to an article, or throw some correct terminology at me, I'd appreciate it :). Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable. Essentially, it's equivalent to the `Number()` constructor. Check this link for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262174/javascript-input-numbers

Comment: Exactly same:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188998/obj-length-obj-length-in-javascript  do you even try searching before posting question..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's checking if the `length` property is numeric. When the unary `+` is applied, it will return the numeric representation of an object or `NaN`, which will be the basis for which the comparison will pass or fail. For the first case, if `obj` doesn't have a `length` property it will be `+undefined` which will return `NaN`. And if `obj.length` is numeric, the condition will pass.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong (or it may was only correct in the past?). The unary operator does not use the `.length` property on an object. Instead, it uses the `valueOf`key of an object to try to cast it into a number. It works the same as the `Number()` constructor. You can use the unary operator if you want to e. g. convert a string of `"3"`into a number type.

Comment: @Xen_mar I meant that the expression `obj.length == +obj.length` is checking if the `length` property is numeric. I didn't mean that the unary plus is checking `length`. Sorry if that was unclear.