# Bug in Javascript parseInt method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

Parsing a string using parseInt method returns invalid output .

Code :

```
parseInt("08");
```

Excepted Output :

```
8
```

Real Output :

```
0
```

Code [This returns output correctly] :

```
parseInt("8")
```

Output :

```
8
```

Why it happens ?

Comment: Simple googling would also have solved this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Googling your exact question title also brings up the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the base:

```
parseInt("08",10); //=>8
```

Otherwise JavaScript doesn't know if you are in decimal, hexadecimal or binary. 
(This is a best practise you should always use if you use parseInt.)

Answer (score 2):

Also see [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Number_and_String_functions):

```
Number("08"); // => 8
```

- [What is the difference between parseInt() and Number()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number)
- [What is the difference between parseInt(string) and Number(string) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You should tell parseInt its 10 based:

```
parseInt("08", 10);
```

[JavaScript parseInt() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

> If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
>
> If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is
>   deprecated If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>   (decimal)

http://jsfiddle.net/YChK5/

Answer (score 0):

Strings with a leading zero are often interpreted as octal values. Since octal means, that only numbers from 0-7 have a meaning, "08" is converted to "0". Specify the base to fix this problem:

```
parseInt("08", 10); // base 10
```

As usual, the MDN is a good source of information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix