# What is the difference between Number(...) and parseFloat(...)

Tags: javascript, string-conversion

[What is the difference between parseInt(string) and Number(string) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4564158/561731) has been asked previously.

But the answers basically focused on the `radix` and the ability of `parseInt` to take a string like `"123htg"` and turn it into `123`.

What I am asking here is if there is any big difference between the returns of `Number(...)` and `parseFloat(...)` when you pass it an **actual number string** with no radix at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No. Both will result in the internal [`ToNumber(string)`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) function being called.

From [ES5 section 15.7.1](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.1) (The Number Constructor Called as a Function):

> When `Number` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion...
>
> Returns a Number value (not a Number object) computed by `ToNumber(value)` if value was supplied, else returns `+0`.

From [ES5 section 15.1.2.3](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.3) (parseFloat (string)):

> ...
>   If neither `trimmedString` nor any prefix of `trimmedString` satisfies the syntax of a `StrDecimalLiteral` (see 9.3.1)
>   ...

And [9.3.1](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) is the section titled "ToNumber Applied to the String Type", which is what the first quote is referring to when it says `ToNumber(value)`.

---

*Update* (see comments)

By calling the `Number` constructor with the `new` operator, you will get an instance of the `Number` object, rather than a numeric literal. For example:

```
typeof new Number(10); //object
typeof Number(10); //number
```

This is defined in [section 15.7.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.2) (The Number Constructor):

> When `Number` is called as part of a `new` expression it is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.

Comment: You'll get a Number object back, in non-strict comparisons it's `valueOf` method will be called, but strict comparisons with non-objects will fail. It's just a bad idea to mess around with `Number` objects IMO (and for what it's worth, Crockford doesn't like them either)

Answer (score 59):

The internal workings are not that different, as @James Allardic already answered. There is a difference though. Using `parseFloat`, a (trimmed) string starting with one or more numeric characters followed by alphanumeric characters can convert to a Number, with `Number` that will not succeed. As in:

```
parseFloat('3.23abc'); //=> 3.23
Number('3.23abc'); //=> NaN
```

In both conversions, the input string is trimmed, by the way:

```
parseFloat('  3.23abc '); //=> 3.23
Number('   3.23 '); //=> 3.23
```

Comment: +1, this is true, but in the circumstances defined in the question, there is no difference - "when you pass it an actual number string". Assuming I've understood that correctly anyway.

Comment: Another difference is the result of `"    "` and `""` where in both cases Number will give `0` but parseFloat gives `NaN`.

Comment: I know about this. I even stated that in the OP... that is **not** what I was asking....

Comment: also `parseFloat('1.2.3'); // 1.2` vs `Number('1.2.3'); // NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Not a whole lot of difference, as long as you're sure there's nothing but digits in your string. If there are, `Number` will return `NaN`. 
Another problem that you might get using the `Number` constructor is that co-workers might think you forgot the `new` keyword, and add it later on, causing strict comparisons to fail `new Number(123) === 123` --> false whereas `Number(123) === 123` --> true.

In general, I prefer to leave the `Number` constructor for what it is, and just use the shortest syntax there is to *cast* to an int/float: `+numString`, or use `parse*`.

Comment: This is not the case.  `Number ("3 - 1")` will produce a Number with a value of 3.

Answer (score -1):

When not using `new` to create a wrapper object for a numerical value, `Number` is relegated to simply doing type conversion from string to number.

'parseFloat' on the other hand, as you mentioned, can parse a floating point number from any string that starts with a digit, a decimal, or +/-

So, if you're only working with strings that contain only numerical values, `Number(x)` and `parseFloat(x)` will result in the same values

Answer (score -1):

Please excuse me posting yet another answer, but I just got here via a Google search and did not find all of the details that I wanted. Running the following code in Node.js:

```
var vals = ["1", "1.1", "0", "1.1abc", "", " ", null];
for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
  var ifTest = false;
  if(vals[i])
  {
    ifTest = true;
  }
  console.log("val=" + vals[i] + ", Number()=" + Number(vals[i])+ ", parseFloat()=" + parseFloat(vals[i]) + ", if()=" + ifTest);
}
```

gives the following output:

```
val=1, Number()=1, parseFloat()=1, if()=true
val=1.1, Number()=1.1, parseFloat()=1.1, if()=true
val=0, Number()=0, parseFloat()=0, if()=true
val=1.1abc, Number()=NaN, parseFloat()=1.1, if()=true
val=, Number()=0, parseFloat()=NaN, if()=false
val= , Number()=0, parseFloat()=NaN, if()=true
val=null, Number()=0, parseFloat()=NaN, if()=false
```

Some noteworthy takeaways:

1. If protecting with an if(val) before trying to convert to number, then parseFloat() will return a number except in the whitespace case.
2. Number returns a number in all cases except for non-numeric characters aside from white-space.

Please feel free to add any test cases that I may be missing.