# Compare numeric values in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below

```
var nums = ["1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5"];
```

Here I am trying to compare the values in array and test whether the values are in ascending order or not.

If two array values are same, I need to skip that. If order is like 1,3,2.. then I will throw an error that they are in wrong order. I want to use pure javascript here.

Comment: What did you try so far and what issues have you encountered?

Comment: And what is your specific problem? Do you know how to iterate over an array? How to compare two values? How to convert a string to a number?

Comment: technically you have an array of strings.

Comment: is it possible to check this for var dates = ["mar 1", "mar 2", "mar 2", "mar 3", "mar 4", "mar 4", "mar 5"]; ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems easy:

```
function isAscending(arr){
    asc = true;
    for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(Number(arr[i]) < Number(arr[i-1])){
            asc = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return asc
}
```

Comment: @halex didn't notice it was strings, fixed

Comment: `Number` would be more appropriate than `parseFloat`.

Comment: @FelixKling not a big difference, but changed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988547/what-is-the-difference-between-number-and-parsefloat)

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through each pair of items using parseInt() to get the numeric value out of the strings and after the loop, compare the value of the incremented index to the number of pairs.

EDIT: As suggested by Rick Hitchcock, instead of breaking from the loop, we can just return false if any pair is not ascending or equal and true if the whole loop went through.

```
function isAscending(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < (array.length - 1); i++) {
        if (parseInt(array[i]) > parseInt(array[i+1])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could replace `break` with `return false`, and replace `return (i == nPairs)` with `return true`.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery

```
var num = [1,5,3,3,4,4];
var sortedNum = num.slice(0).sort(function(a,b) {
    return a-b;
});
//if its sorted
if(num.join(',') === sortedNum.join(',')) {
    //get only unique elems
    var finalArr = $.grep(num, function(el, index) {
        return index === $.inArray(el, num);
    });
    console.log(finalArr);
}
else {
    console.log('Error Not Sorted');
}
```