# jQuery test for 00, 0.0 and 0,0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field `currency` that is disabled if the value on another field `fee` is empty or zero.

**Html**

```
Fee: <input id="fee"><br>
Currency: <input id="currency"><br>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#fee").on('input', function() {
$('#currency').prop('disabled', (this.value === '0' || this.value === ''));  
})
.trigger('input');
```

or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zp9ug1m/29/)

What I now try to achieve is that the field `currency` is also disabled if someone enters `00` or `0.0` or `0,0` which currently is not the case. I have to test for both a `.` and a `,` in my field, because users can enter numbers with both values as a delimiter.

I through of changing `this.value === '0'` to `this.value < '0.000000001' || this.value < '0,000000001'`, but then it still won't work with `00`. Also something like `0,1` will be disabled (which it shouldn't), and that is because of the comma `,` which does not work in a number?

Is there perhaps an easy (or difficult) solution to my problem?

**edit** to clarify: the field `currency` should be disabled when the user enters `0`, `00` (or any number of zeros), `0.0`(or any more zeros) and `0,0`(or any more zeros). The field should be enabled if the user enters something like `09` or `0,5` or `0.1`.

Comment: Can you clarify what are the expected valid values or rather only which values are invalid. An if/else condition would suffice in the above case. if not a regular expression would work.

Comment: @Bsienn I made an edit to clarify. Hope it is clear like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [validation if value is empty or zero ('0'), but what if it's "0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566870/validation-if-value-is-empty-or-zero-0-but-what-if-its-0-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to work a little on the input value prior to compare it.

1. replace coma by dot (if any)
2. convert to a float number

So now, there are two possibilities, you have a valid float number or a NAN (not A Number). The second case is easy to determine using [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) which returns a boolean.

```js
$("#fee").on('input', function() {

  // Replace all coma by dot and parse as a float number
  var value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(",","."));

  $('#currency').prop('disabled', ( value === 0 || isNaN(value) ));  
})
.trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Fee: <input id="fee"><br>
Currency: <input id="currency"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.value.replace(/[0+.,]+/,'') == 0

```
 $("#fee").on('input', function() {
   $('#currency').prop('disabled', (this.value.replace(/[0\+\.,]+/,'') == 0));  
  }).trigger('input');
```