# JavaScript: Intended behavior of Number()

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, linefeed

I'm currently reading string integers from files and passing them to functions. Since most files have a trailing line feed, I was wondering about the behavior of `Number()`.

To get the `max_pid` variable from a RHEL kernel file, I'm using an asynchronous read.

```
var options = {
  encoding: 'utf8'
};

fs.readFile('/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max', options, function (err, data) {
  var max_pid = Number(data);

  // or trim the string first
  var max_pid = Number(data.trim());
});
```

The variable `data` for my system returned the string `'32768\n'`, and using `Number()` on that string strips the line feed. Is this the intended behavior of `Number()`, or should I be using `str.trim()` on the variable before passing it to `Number()`?

I ask this for reasons of consistency across environments, as well as proper use of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Section 9.3.1 of the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/ECMA-262.pdf), conversion of a string to a number will automatically strip leading and trailing white space. I'd be shocked if there was a JavaScript engine that did not conform to this part of the spec. The call to `trim()` is unnecessary (but harmless).

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace is automatically trimmed from the start and end of strings.  It won't remove whitespace from the middle of a number, e.g., `"12 345"` (evaluates to `NaN`).  And if there are any non-numeric characters, you'll receive `NaN`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4564158/1074592) for more information.