# Javascript/jquery get number value inside of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span id="rate">2388</span>

var = $("#rate")...
```

I need get number value inside of element. any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var number = +$("#rate").text();
//           |              \______get text of span as string
//           |_________________unary plus converts to numeric
```

Comment: ha got it!, so + is the same as Number();

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text inside your `span` using **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method and **[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** to convert it to number:

```
var rateVal = parseInt($("#rate").text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also this

```
var result = Number($("#rate").html());
```

But becareful to use Number functon, Please have look this discussion for difference between parseInt and Number.

[What is the difference between parseInt(string) and Number(string) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript), as Roko indicated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan now edited the answer with parseInt.

Comment: you should remove your answer, cause otherwise it's a duplicate of Felix's answer, and BTW you're missing the `radix` parameter.

Comment: Fexlix is using text(), and I used html(), does this consider as duplicate answer?

Comment: Almost, .html() is even the worse scenario, but now that you're using parseInt() makes no difference between your and Felix's. + You're still missing the parseInt radix parameter.

Comment: I just want to give another option, Does changing parseInt to Number prevent the deleting answer?

Comment: `Number()` only takes one argument, doesn't it?