# Using Number() vs. parseInt() to do type conversion? Which should I use when?

Tags: javascript, casting

For type conversion, when should one use the primitive wrapper `Number()` and when should one use `parseInt()`?

I'm aware that `parseInt()` allows you to specify a radix, will truncate decimals so that they become integers, and will parse up until the first `NaN` it encounters in the input. The MDN documentation on the `Number()` wrapper was less helpful.

My questions:

1. Is there a general preference for using one or the other?
2. Are there performance differences?
3. Are there edge case differences in the two implementations?

Things I've tried:

1. Reading the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) MDN documentation.
2. Googling
3. Searching StackOverflow
4. Searching StackExchange

Comment: There's also just the `+` operator which will also do a conversion to a number.  I would guess (but don't know for sure) that it's the same as `Number(x)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number

Comment: I wish this wouldn't have been marked as a duplicate. I came to this question FROM the supposed duplicate because I had this same question. The linked question describes what each one does but does NOT describe reasons why you should use one in place of another in certain situations.

Comment: FYI, @sjngm was kind enough to answer this question in the "EDIT #2" section of [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4564199/306179) on the linked question.