# Why use Number.parseInt instead of parseInt()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, built-in

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt):

> This method behaves identically to the global function parseInt()

But, as it's experimental, [the compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt#Browser_compatibility) is worst. For example, is not available in IE or Safari.

So, why should a developer use Number.parseInt()?

Comment: because the developer uses a JS Engine that supports it?

Comment: I don't think there's a better reason to use it. The function is exactly the same. They're just trying to remove global functions in ECMAScript 6, and making them class methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between parseInt(string) and Number(string) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript)

Comment: From the docs you've linked: "`its purpose is modularization of globals`".

Comment: The problem it's not supported in IE

Comment: @RomainBraun Do you have a source for the ECMAScript 6 global function removing? Because that would be a very good reason to switch to Number.* functions (reason is "global ones are deprecated and will be removed") Btw, `Number.parseFloat = parseFloat` should be a simple polyfill for IE (until you stop supporting this obsolete version of Edge)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The use of `Number.parseInt` being encouraged over `parseInt()` is due to a trend in the JavaScript community of get away from using globals. The Mozilla documentation on `Number.parseInt` states:

> ...and is part of ECMAScript 2015 (**its purpose is modularization of globals**).

There you have it. It's because of global-phobia :)

Comment: What trend? I have never stumble up on someone ever using `Number.NaN` over just writing `NaN`. Maybe it's just me living under a rock

Comment: Yes it is you living under a rock.