# Meteor / MongoDB: insert integer instead of string on form submit

Tags: forms, mongodb, meteor, insert, submit

I'm working through David's tutorial on Meteor at http://meteortips.com/.

How do I insert an integer instead of string on form submit?

I think the following line needs to clarify that it's an integer, but I'm not sure how.

```
var playerScoreVar = event.target.playerScore.value;
```

Here's my whole code.

```
 Template.addPlayerForm.events({

  'submit form': function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var playerNameVar = event.target.playerName.value;
      var playerScoreVar = event.target.playerScore.value;
      PlayersList.insert({
          name: playerNameVar,
          score: playerScoreVar,
      });
      event.target.playerName.value = ""
      event.target.playerScore.value = ""
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just convert it to an integer prior to the `insert`:

```js
var playerScoreVar = parseInt(event.target.playerScore.value, 10);
```

or

```js
var playerScoreVar = Number(event.target.playerScore.value);
```

You can see the differences explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript);

Comment: Thanks, what does the 10 mean on the end of that line?  

And why can't I just write 'Int' somewhere in that line and be done with it? :D

Comment: It's the radix (base). See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Got it, so I either have to parseInt or make sure they're only putting numbers in the form element in the first place.  Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you extract the value from an input it will be a string, so you'll have to do the conversion. And yes, you probably want some other kind of form validation on top of this.