# Read hex number from file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have (.hex) file that represent data in hexadicimal format. here are sample of the file:

> :100080000C9408010C9408010C9408010C940801CC
>   :100090000C9408010C9408010C9408010C9428019C
>   :1000A0000C9408010C9408010C9408010C940801AC
>   :1000B0000C9408010C9408010C9408010C9408019C
>   :1000C0000C9408010C9408010C9408010C9408018C
>   :1000D0000C9408010C9408010C9408010C9408017C

I write the following nodejs code to read the file and convert it to Buffer in the end to be sent using serial.

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('./code.hex', function(err, code){

    var str = code.toString();
    var line = str.split('\n');

    addr = line[1].slice(1, 9);
    //addr_num = Number(addr, 'hex');

    data = line[1].slice(9, (line[1].length - 3));
    console.log(data);
    var buf = new Buffer(data, 'hex');
}
```

The first 8 digits in the line are part of an address and the rest of the line is the data. What I want is to read the `addr` as a number compare it with other variables using `if` condition. When I tried `addr_num = Number(addr, 'hex');` the result was `NAN`. Is there a way to read it as a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
parseInt(addr, 16)
```

instead of:

```
Number(addr, 'hex')
```

to parse a string with radix 16 (hex) as a number.

There are a couple of differences between the two which you can read up on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number), but essentially `parseInt()` allows you to specify the radix whereas `Number()` doesn't.

Both will try to guess the radix based on the format of the string to parse (if not specified), so in theory you could also do:

```
Number('0x' + addr)
```

or

```
parseInt('0x' + addr)
```

but since the string you're reading from the file isn't in this format and you'd have to stitch `'0x'` in front of it, you're probably better off just using `parseInt(addr, 16)`.