# after using $and query, the results aren't render on DOM

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am building some little log reporting with meteor.

have a dead simple table, that should contain all the data that received from the external mongodb server.

the html:

```
 <tbody>
  {{#each impressions}}
  <tr>
    {{> impression}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

js :

```
Meteor.subscribe('impressions');
...
...
Template.logResults.helpers({
'impressions': function() {
var sTs = Router.current().params.fromTs;
var eTs = Router.current().params.toTs;
return Impressions.find({});
}
});
```

So far, so good. BUT, when I am changing the query to this one :

```
Impressions.find({
  $and: [{
    ts: {
      $gte: sTs
    }
  }, {
    ts: {
      $lte: eTs
    }
  }]
});
```

The results aren't displayed on the HTML DOM,
I tried to debug that, and created a `console.log` of this exact query,
and surprisingly all the correct results return successfully to the console.

screenshot attached.
I am probably doing something wrong, maybe with publish/subscribe thing.

help someone?

Thanks.
P.S. I removed the insecure and auto-publish,
have this code on the server folder

```
Meteor.publish('impressions', function() {
  return Impressions.find();
});
```

and this code on the main lib folder

```
Impressions = new Mongo.Collection("banners");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbgda.png)

Comment: and also tried to use .fetch(); but it returned empty array.

Comment: My hunch is that this is a string to integer conversion problem. Are ets and sts are supposed to be numbers?

Comment: yes they should...
edit : OMG wooot ?!
first, thank you so much !
secound, you have great hunch,
third, why the results returned on console but not on HTML ?

Comment: I'll write a more complete answer when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: Note that `$and:` is the default, you can write simply as `Impressions.find({ ts: { $gte: sTs }, ts: { $lte: eTs }});` You typically only need to invoke `$and:` in combination with `$or:`.

Comment: @MichelFloyd correct, except in this case. You need the `$and` if the same field is used in more than one expression.

Comment: Good to know! thanks @MichelFloyd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router stores the parameters for the current route as strings (which makes sense because URLs are strings), so you need to explicitly convert the values to integers before querying the database. Give something like this a try:

```js
var sTs = Number(Router.current().params.fromTs);
var eTs = Number(Router.current().params.toTs);
```

Notes:

1. `parseInt` or `parseFloat` may be a better choice depending on the nature of your input. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript) for more details.
2. You could do the type conversion in the router itself and pass the values in the data context to the helpers. See [this section](https://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data) of the iron router guide.
3. I suspect it worked when you typed it into the console because you used numbers instead of strings. E.g. `ts: {$gte: 123}` instead of `ts: {$gte: '123'}`.