# Get only numbers from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string such as **`12  3   44 5 \n 7 88`**
I want get from string only numbers and write them in array: `[12,3,4,5,7,88]`.
I want do it whith RegExp:

```
  var str='12  3   44 5 \n 7 88';
  alert(str);
  var re =/^\S+$/;
  var res=re.exec(str);
  alert(res[0]);
  alert(res[1]);
  alert(res[2]);
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/javascript-get-number-from-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way:

```js
var str = '12  3   44 5 \n 7 88';
//if there matches, store them into the array, otherwise set 'numbers' to empty array
var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g)?str.match(/\d+/g):[];
//to convert the strings to numbers
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    numbers[i]=+numbers[i]
}
alert(numbers);
```

Why? `.match()` is just an easier thing to use there. `\d+` gets a number of any length, flag `g` returns all the matches, not only the first match.

If you also want to match the floats, the regex would be `/\d+([\.,]\d+)?/g`. It'll also match 42,12 or 42.12.

Comment: Except this returns an array of strings, not integers.

Comment: @Andy okay, edited. This doesn't really matter though, they can be converted on fly...

Comment: You can also also do [`var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);`](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/46dofdev/).

Comment: Or use parseInt instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript

Comment: @roland where would you suggest to put `parseInt`? I'm converting to number with `+`, seems to be shorter.

Comment: `var str = '';` or anything without a match, `for` or `map` will fail.

Comment: You do realise that `a` is a global variable as you have not declared it?

Comment: @Xotic Of course I do. I don't care though, how is it a problem?

Comment: A quote from David Walsh - `Leaking global variables is bad practice and a result of sloppy coding. `. No problem for me,  it's a practice that I avoid.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alteranative

```js
var s = '12  3   44 5 \n 7 88';
var numbers = s.split(/[^\d]+/).map(Number);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(numbers);
console.log(numbers);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

With `split` you will never have a situation like where `exec` or `match` could be `null`

Note: this does not take into account negative numbers or floating point or scientific numbers etc. An empty string will also produce `[0]`, so specification is key.