# Unable to convert a string to integer

Tags: javascript, integer

I have an AJAX request in my page and the *.php* page echoes an integer or string based on the event in the page. But, when the variable reaches to my actual *javascript* file , it becomes string. For example 4 changes to "4". And that is making my program problematic because my program has to run according to the responseText. I have a XMLHTTPRequestObject.onload function that works like:

```
    if(typeof XMLHTTPRequest.responseText === "number"){
// do something
}
```

My php script provides a result either integer or string and if the result is string, then I can perform the function but it is not happening like so. I tried changing the variable using `parseInt()` and `Number()` but then, everything gets changed to number either it was s string. So, how do I tackle this problem? Please do help!

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` will **always** be a string. You can encode your response as JSON and then parse the response.

Comment: `if (XMLHTTPRequest.responseText == 2)` will convert "2" to a number before testing it

Comment: so, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the string to number using `Number`. If you receive `NaN` you know the string wasn't a valid number say `123notANumber` for example, see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript) for more information.

```
if (isNaN(Number('123test')) {
  // This is a string
}
else {
  // It's a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` will **always** be a string. The easiest solution is likely to use the `Number` constructor to convert that string to a number. If the string doesn't represent an integer, `Number` will return `NaN`. So instead of what you have currently, you could do somthing like this:

```
const parsed = Number(XMLHTTPRequest.responseText);
if(isNaN(parsed)){
    //handle case where response is a string
} else {
    //handle case where response is a number
}
```

Comment: Parse int will not return NaN see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript

Comment: good catch, edited

Comment: It is still incorrect parseInt('123test') returns `123` not NaN.