# Values are wildly off in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am calculating values, snapshotting them and send them into a interval. But the issue is, is its wildly increasing what the sum should be.

Here is the calculations:

```js
// Set up mob attributes - SNAPSHOT
const mobId = '1';
var mob = {
  mhp: (mobId + 10) * 15,
  hp: (mobId + 10) * 15,
  dmg: (mobId + 2) * 3,
  defenseRating: (mobId + 3) * 4,
  hitRating: (mobId + 2) * 2,
  critRating: (mobId + 3) * 2,
  critDmg: (mobId + 2) * 2,
  dodgeRating: (mobId + 1) * 3,
  firstHitRating: (mobId + 3) * 4,
};
console.log(mob);
```

I don't know about you, but in what world does 11 * 15 = 1650. This is the calculations BEFORE I send it through the interval, so it isn't messing up there. It is the intial calculations that being very weird.

Note: It may be worth noting that I am doing this through a socket event:
`socket.on('fight mob', (mobId) => {`
I doubt that is the issue but I am at a loss right now.

Comment: Looks like `mobId` is a string. Cast it to a number first, else `+` will concatenate

Comment: Before using the + operator, which concatenates strings, make sure mobId is an integer, you can use mobId = parseInt(mobId, 10);

Without that casting, mhp is 110 * 15 (110 is the result of concatenating 1 and 10), and 110*15 = 1650.

Comment: I don't know about you but for me string addition means concatenation not mathematical addition. If `mobId = '1'` then `mobId + 10 === '110'`.

Comment: Slow down william, you are obviously full of anger as you are writing this, try to debug the code before you post it here.

Comment: Uhm, not angry, was just confused, stop assuming things.

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition). It says in the example: *"Number + String -> concatenation"*

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your mobId variable is a string, not a number.

(1 + 10) * 15 = 165

("1" + 10) * 15 = 1650

To resolve this, you can coerce mobId's type using Number():

(Number(mobId) + 10) * 15 = 165

Good luck!

Comment: Question: whats the difference between: `parseInt(mobId)` and `Number(mobId)` because they seem to do the exact same thing.

Comment: "Number(object) tries to convert the entire string to a number(which can also be a float) while parseInt(object) parses up to first non-digit and returns whatever value has been parsed. Also, the complete format of parseInt() is parseInt(object, radix) where radix defines the base of the integer to be parsed into."

Comment: This question is to be addresed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript. Mate you need to google

Answer (score 1):

Due to loose typing, JavaScript automatically tries to change the types of variables when performing operations on them. In your case, `mobId` is a string and not a number. So, instead of addition, JavaScript performs concatenation.

So the operation

```
(mobId + 10) * 15
```

becomes something like this for `mobId` being `'1'`:

```
'110' * 15
```

Again, JavaScript's type caster kicks in, but this time it converts the string to number for multiplication, so the result becomes `1650`.

To mitigate, convert the `mobId` to number first. Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` for that:

```
mobId = parseInt(mobId, 10);
(mobId + 10) * 15 // Yields 165
```