# Why does Number(null) return 0, and parseFloat(null) return NaN?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a helper function that will cast a `String` coming from an `<input type="text" />` to a `Number`.

As I wasn't sure whether to use `parseFloat(str)` or `Number(str)` I doublechecked how they handle potentially problematic arguments.

See:

```js
console.log(Number(null)); // 0
console.log(parseFloat(null)); // NaN
console.log(parseInt(null)); // NaN
console.log(isNaN(null)); // false
```

Both `parseFloat` and `parseInt` return `NaN`, whereas `Number` returns `0`. `Number` seems more coherent here with `isNaN(null)`.

Why is that?

Comment: its part of the standard. read the docs

Comment: for validation use regexp `/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/.test(stringWithNumber)`

Comment: This question has been answered on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript)

Comment: [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) !== [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). *Removed explanation, better in answers below.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `parseInt/Float` convert their argument to a string, read it char by char from the left and try to make a number from what they've found. Since `String(null)` is `"null"` and a decimal number cannot start with `"n"`, `parseInt(null)` will be `NaN`. If you provide a different base, where `n`, `u` and `l` are digits, the result will be different:

```js
console.log(parseInt(null, 32))
```

- `Number` converts its argument as a whole into a number. `Number(null)` returns `+0` because the ECMA committee wants it to: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tonumber . This is probably for historical reasons.
- global `isNaN` (not to confuse with `Number.isNaN`) applies `Number` to its argument and returns `true` if the result is `NaN`. Since `Number(null)` is `+0`, `isNaN(null)` is `false`.

Hope this sheds some light...

Answer (score 3):

`Number` constructor tries to coerce the argument to number. So empty string '', `false`, `null` and all falsy values become 0.

Similarly, `Number(true)` will return 1. `Number('some string')` will be `NaN` as 'some string' cannot be converted to a number.

Note that as pointed out in the comments, `Number(undefined)` is NaN and not 0 in arithmetic operations. (Read here https://codeburst.io/understanding-null-undefined-and-nan-b603cb74b44c)

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: It is not used as _constructor_, by the way!

Comment: `Number(undefined)` is NaN, not 0.

Comment: Thanks @georg, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

NaN stands for "Not a Number". ParseFloat and ParseInt return real numbers and integers, so this is like an error returned by the function. Number(), on the other hand, represents the object's **value**. For instance, Number(false) will output 0.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be quite subtle with how `parseInt` and `parseFloat` work:

If the argument passed to `parseInt`/`parseFloat` is not a `String` (which null isn't), then it calls `toString(null)` which returns `"[object Undefined]"`.

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt