# JSLint says "missing radix parameter"

Tags: javascript, jslint, radix

I ran  JSLint on this JavaScript code and it said:

> Problem at line 32 character 30: Missing radix parameter.

This is the code in question:

```
imageIndex = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1))-1;
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1171, accepted):

It always a good practice to pass radix with parseInt -

```
parseInt(string, radix)
```

For decimal -

```
parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1), 10)
```

If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:

- If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
- If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
- If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)

([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt))

Comment: From the sounds of it, the default IS 10.  If it doesn't begin with 0x or 0, it defaults to a radix of 10.  But it is best practice to specify a radix even if it is the default value, sort of like specifying the definition of "this" to an array.map function.

Comment: thats so unreasonable...  by that logic there should be a third param to represent the radix of the radix argument itself

Comment: Agree with other commenters.  Why is it good to provide a radix value when the default is 10?  This defies common convention.

Comment: Can somebody like @vbullinger mentioned say this is default 10... for typescript this error was annoying to solve.

Comment: @Jayendra Thank you for your explanation. Could you also further elaborate on how to define the radix? I see this warning message when I am using radix, _**'radix' was used before it was defined.**_.

Comment: Add 10 as the radix to get another lint error... `Redundant radix parameter`

Comment: @Nishant: The `radix` argument is a numeric value, not a string representation of a numeric value, so there is no radix to specify.

Comment: @vbullinger and others, the radix is there so that you can clearly see, **what are you parsing to**. And that it is exactly the output, you are expeting from `parseInt` to provide. Look on the internet, or just here, how many questions are about `parseInt`s output being wrong, when radix wasn't provided.

Comment: Sure thing, @PavelHasala. But... let's default it to ten. Thanks.

Comment: The default value of `radix` as a function argument is conditional, not `10`. The default of those conditions is `10`, but that's not the same thing. `parseInt('0xA') !== parseInt('0xA', 10)` ...it is unexpected.

Comment: Please note that you can also use the as-needed es-lint option so that you only need to specify a radix if the radix != 10 https://eslint.org/docs/rules/radix#options

Comment: @Nishant Why not just use `Number` if that's what you want?

Comment: @Emobe That would be perfect. Just read my comment after a long time. Realize I was indeed looking at it the wrong way like @@tokland said. Strange, my comment was upvoted 56 times

Comment: @Nishant well, your comment does make sense, it's pretty unreasonable to mark a parameter as required when it has a default value. 
However I think the intention of the tslint rule is to try and sway people to use appropriate methods. While parseInt _can_ create a base 10 number, it's intended for different bases too.

Another downside to `parseInt` is that it's a performance hog. https://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/3

So if you're not wanting anything other than base 10, then `Number` would be the way to go imo.

Comment: I also don't like the look of a 10 in the code that you have to repeat every time.

Comment: I didn't know the default would be different in case the number starts with 0. That is probably the actual reason why it complains about it. I always assumed if you don't provide it, it would always try to parse it as decimal. In case you could have paddings with 0s, that should be a concern

Answer (score 169):

To avoid this warning, instead of using:

```
parseInt("999", 10);
```

You may replace it by:

```
Number("999");
```

<sup>Note that parseInt and Number have [different behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090577/1476885), but in some cases, one can replace the other.</sup>

Comment: There are also big performance differences between `parseInt` and `Number`. Here is an [old performance test](https://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/3).

Comment: Chrome 77: `Number()` is 6x faster than `parseInt()`

Comment: The real answer.

Comment: `parseInt` will parse up to the first non-digit character, where `Number` will return `nan`.  Don't use Number where you could get values like `32px`.

Answer (score 55):

I'm not properly answering the question but, I think it makes sense to clear **why we should specify the radix**.

On MDN documentation we can read that:

> If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the
> following:
>
> - [...]
> - If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.
>   **ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix
>   when using parseInt.**
> - [...]

Source: [MDN parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Yes but the Typescript compiler will insert it, so why should you bother?

Comment: @Spock Because TSLint complains that it's not there. And down the rabbit hole we go...

Comment: Yeah true.. that's why I just disable this lint rule. Still don't understand why an OPTIONAL parameter trips a lint complaint.. oh well

Comment: @Spock Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 34):

You can turn off this rule if you wish to skip that test.

Insert:

```
radix: false
```

Under the "`rules`" property in the `tslint.json` file.

It's not recommended to do that if you don't understand this exception.

Comment: I'm going to use this since code runs just fine without radix

Answer (score 22):

Adding the following on top of your JS file will tell JSHint to supress the radix warning:

```
/*jshint -W065 */
```

See also: http://jshint.com/docs/#options

Comment: What jshint option does this correspond to? I'm using SublimeLint to run jshint in my editor, and it only takes a hash of option: value pairs for it's setting, so I don't think I can apply your "-W065" suggestion.

Comment: You can use `"-W065": true`, e.g. in a `.jshintrc` file.

Comment: -1 Please don't do this, just add the radix you want to parse in

Comment: The more strongly-typed a language, the more opportunities for compiler optimization, which is why it is throwing the warn.

Comment: in modern JS, IMO adding the radix actually makes it more unclear what the function is doing. It's in the position you might expect a default to go if you don't know the function signature. It makes no sense that you have to specify a radix.

Answer (score 22):

Prior to ECMAScript 5, parseInt() also autodetected octal literals, which caused problems because many developers assumed a leading 0 would be ignored.

So Instead of :

```
var num = parseInt("071");      // 57
```

Do this:

```
var num = parseInt("071", 10);  // 71

var num = parseInt("071", 8);

var num = parseFloat(someValue);
```

[Reference](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/radix)

Answer (score 6):

Simply add your custom rule in .eslintrc which looks like that 
`"radix": "off"`
and you will be free of this eslint unnesesery warning.
This is for the eslint linter.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it with just using the +foo, to convert the string.

Keep in mind it's not great for readability (dirty fix).

```
console.log( +'1' )
// 1 (int)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply add this line right above your parseInt line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

This will disable eslint check for the next line. Use this if you only need to skip one or two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Just put an empty string in the radix place, because parseInt() take two arguments:

parseInt(string, radix);

string
The value to parse. If the string argument is not a string, then it is converted to a string (using the ToString abstract operation). Leading whitespace in the string argument is ignored.

radix
An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above-mentioned string. Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.

<strike>imageIndex = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1))-1;</strike>
**`imageIndex = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1), '')-1;`**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `substring` function you could use `.slice()`

```
    imageIndex = parseInt(id.slice(-1)) - 1;
```

Here, -1 in slice indicates that to start slice from the last index.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the [official ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/radix) state:

> [...] if the code is targeting only ES5-compliant environments passing the radix 10 may be redundant. In such a case you might want to disallow using such a radix.

So, when using ESLint, add `radix` to the configuration:

```
// .eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  rules: {
    radix: ['error', 'as-needed'],
  },
};
```