# how to prevent isNaN before dates are selected in Datepicker

Tags: javascript

I would like to prevent NaN from showing up in these text boxes:  "total_full", "total_half", "total_single".  I have **tried** setting the initial value of all calculating / number fields to "0", but "total_single" is still NaN until "check_out" date is selected and the total_days_acc is updated?

I am not sure how much of the code I am supposed to put here, and I would hate to leave something important out, so here is a link to a question where i incorrectly posted "all" the coding.  :

[hide / show fields based on input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006316/hide-show-fields-based-on-input-value)

Thank you

```
<td>Accommodation:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Check in Date</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="check_in_date" id="check_in_date" class="datepicker" /></td>
    <td><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td><p>Check out Date</p></td>
    <td><p>
      <input type="text" name="check_out_date" id="check_out_date" class="datepicker" />
        </p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total Days Accommodation</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total_days_acc" id="total_days_acc" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Number of Rooms:</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Single</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="no_of_rooms_single" id="no_of_rooms_single" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Double / Twin</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="no_of_rooms_double" id="no_of_rooms_double" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contact Person</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="contact_person" id="contact_person" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telephone Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tel_no" id="tel_no" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Fax Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fax_no" id="fax_no" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cell_no" id="cell_no" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Full Day Conference @ R260.00 p/p</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="full_day" id="full_day" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total Cost Full Day</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total_full" id="total_full" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Half Day Conference @ R240.00 p/p</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="half_day" id="half_day" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total Cost Half Day</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total_half" id="total_half" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Single Rooms @ R480.00 p/p</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="single_rooms" id="single_rooms" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total Cost Single Rooms</td>
    <td><input name="total_single" type="text" id="total_single" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Double / Twin Rooms @ R720.00 p/p</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="double_rooms" id="double_rooms" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total Cost Double / Twin</td>
    <td><input name="total_double" type="text" id="total_double" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data Projector @ R400.00 rental p/day</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="data_proj" id="data_proj" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total Cost Projector Rental</td>
    <td><input name="total_project" type="text" id="total_project" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sub Total</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" id="sub_total" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="23">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  </form>
</table>

</div>

<div id="hideme">
Hello Hideme
</div>


<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
//Datepicker
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+100M +10D",dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'})
    ({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
        });

//Datepicker Enquiry Date Set to Today
var enquiry_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date());
document.getElementById('enquiry_date').value = enquiry_date;


//Datepicker Conference in / out
var calcDate = function() {
    var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 + 1;

    if(days==0) {days=1
    }
    if( days >= 0 ) {
    document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
    } 
        }


$('#conference_date_out').change(calcDate);
$('#conference_date_in').change(calcDate);




//Datepicker Check in  / Out Accommodation
var calcDateAcc = function() {
    var startacc = $('#check_in_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var endacc = $('#check_out_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var daysacc = (endacc - startacc) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;


    if(daysacc==0) daysacc=1
    if( daysacc >= 0 ) {
    document.getElementById('total_days_acc').value = daysacc;
    } 
        }


$('#check_in_date').change(calcDateAcc);
$('#check_out_date').change(calcDateAcc);



//Calculate Total Cost FullDay Conference
function calculateFull()
{
    var fulldays = parseInt(document.getElementById("full_day").value);

    var no_of_delegates = parseInt(document.getElementById("no_of_delegates").value);

    var fullprice = 260;

    var resultfull =  fulldays * no_of_delegates * fullprice;

    document.getElementById("total_full").value = resultfull;
    }

    $('#full_day').change(calculateFull).keyup(calculateFull);



//Calculate Half Day conference total   

    function calculateHalf()
{
    var halfdays = parseInt(document.getElementById("half_day").value);

    var no_of_delegates = parseInt(document.getElementById("no_of_delegates").value);

    var halfprice = 240;

    var resulthalf =  halfdays * no_of_delegates * halfprice;

    document.getElementById("total_half").value = resulthalf;
    }

    $('#half_day').change(calculateHalf).keyup(calculateHalf);



//Calculate Total Cost Single Rooms
    function calculateSingle()
{
    var single_rooms = parseInt(document.getElementById("single_rooms").value);

    var total_days_acc = parseInt(document.getElementById("total_days_acc").value);

    var single_rooms_price = 480;

    var resultsingle =  single_rooms * total_days_acc * single_rooms_price;

    document.getElementById("total_single").value = resultsingle;
    }

    $('#single_rooms').change(calculateSingle).keyup(calculateSingle);
    $('#check_in_date').change(calculateSingle);
    $('#check_out_date').change(calculateSingle);


//Hide me Testing   
$("#full_day").keyup(function(){

        if ($('#full_day').val() == "1") {   
            $("#hideme").show("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
        }
        else {
            $("#hideme").hide("fast");    //Slide Up Effect
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should post *as little code as possible* that still expresses all the *functionally relevant components* of the code in question.  Runs of `&nbsp` are not part of your question and definitely should not be included; most of your JS and your input elements probably are relevant and should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just inserting the value into the page, just do this:

```
document.getElementById("total_days").value = isNaN(days) ? 0 : days;
```