# convert a big number string to int

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, int

i have this html

```
<p class="res_current tooltip" name="2.969.226.853.669.634.301.755.392" id="current_metal">3 Q</p>
```

im using this code to get the number of name:

```
var a = document.getElementById('current_metal').name;
```

i need to use a to compare like

if(a < 10) { do something }

but the problem is that when i see a (using alert) it return something like this

-> 2,96922685366e+24

so i cant do the if :(, there is a way to get the FULL number without the "."? or convert it

Comment: Have you tried this asked question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parseInt`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/parseint):

```
parseInt(a, 10);
```

**CAUTION**: [Do not omit the *radix* argument!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7818929/2587420)

Comment: var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('current_metal').name);
    
       alert(a);

but it only return 2,

Comment: parseFloat still returning only the first number =/