# jquery for loop with given start and end

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop

I have 2 input boxes so I enter a "From" and "To" values in each.  For some reason it works in with a certain range only, but can't figure out why.

```
var from = $('#from').val();
var to = $('#to').val();
var total = '';
for (i = from; i <= to; i++)
{
     if (i == to)
        total += i;
     else
        total += i + ',';
}
console.log(total);
```

so this works when doing something like 1-10 but I've tried 8-30 or 8-100 doesn't work...can't seem to figure out why..

Comment: Any clues from the console?

Comment: @Andres: it would be more standard to replace `var total = '';` with `var total = [];` then do `total.push(i);` inside the `for` then `total.join(',')` to get the comma separated list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly turn the values (string) into numbers first, otherwise you're stuck with string comparison, i.e. `'2' > '100'`.

```
var from = +$('#from').val();
var to = +$('#to').val();
```

I'm using the unary `+` operator for that. You could also use this:

```
var from = parseInt($('#from').val(), 10);
var to = parseInt($('#to').val(), 10);
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090577/1338292) to decide which one is better for your purposes. Personally I'd go with the first one, short and sweet :)