# Javascript math is different inside functions

Tags: javascript, math

I have a very stupid problem. This code:

```
var x=5;
console.log(x*20+x-1);
```

prints out 104 as expected but this:

```
function Go(){
    x = document.getElementById("input").value;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(x*20+x-1);
}
```

prints out 5 and then 1004. Why is this?

`console.log(x*20)` prints 100. I tried putting brackets around it and then adding `(x-1)` but it still outputs 1004.

Comment: parseInt(x) and then perform the operations

Comment: `.value` always provides a `String`, which `+` will concatenate rather than add.

Comment: Because `+` is the operator for addition as well as string concatenation.

Comment: `var x="5"; console.log(x*20+x-1);` - is the location *really* the issue?

Comment: Although you do need parseInt(or parseFloat if you need decimal precision), be careful of octal parses. The following link explains in greater detail: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` property of the [input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) is a *string*, so your `x` is actually `"5"`—not the number `5`. What follows is JavaScript’s way of doing implicit type conversion for arithmetics:

```
  "5" * 20 + "5" - 1
= 100      + "5" - 1
= "1005"         - 1
= 1004
```

So in the first step, `"5"` is correctly converted to the number `5`, leaving `100` as the intermediary result. However, adding a string to a number will convert the number into a string, so what happens next is a string concatenation to `"1005"`. Finally, the number `1` is subtracted from the string, which causes the string to be converted to a number again, yielding the final result: `1004`.

To avoid this, you can simply convert the `x` to a number first:

```
var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
x = parseInt(x, 10); // or parseFloat(x) if you’re interested in a decimals
console.log(x * 20 + x - 1);
```

Fun fact: If you wrote `x * 21 - 1`, which is equivalent to your calculation, the problem wouldn’t have appeared.

Comment: parseFloat if decimal precision is needed is worthy of a mention!

Answer (score 1):

The value of an input element is a string value, so what you are getting is:

```
"5" * 20 = 100
100 + "5" = "1005"
"1005" - 1 = 1004
```

This has nothing to do with being in a function or not. Your two code snippets are not equivalent.

You can solve this by doing:

```
function Go(){
    x = +(document.getElementById("input").value);
    console.log(x);
    console.log(x*20+x-1);
}
```

That will convert the input element value to a numeric value at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("input").value` returns a string. You need to convert it to and integer for it to work. So use parseInt()

```
function Go(){
    x = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);
    console.log(x);
    console.log(x*20+x-1);
}
```