# JS how to add instead of concatenate numbers

Tags: javascript, concatenation

This question has an answer:

see - [Javascript variables not adding two variables correctly, only concatenating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661962/javascript-variables-not-adding-two-variables-correctly-only-concatenating)

I am trying to add 5 units to a number but the number is being concatenated instead.

```
 this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x += 5
```

Each time this is run in a loop the outputs are

```
105.00
105.005
105.0055
105.00555
...
```

The output I am looking for is,

```
105.00
110.00
115.00
120.00
...
```

I tried,

```
this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x += parseFloat(5)
```

I also tried this, but get the same results,

```
this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x = this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x + 5
```

Thanks,

Comment: looks like you add something to a string, not a number. why not keep the value of `this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x` as number and use later a fixed value.

Comment: I thought parseFloat() would fix that. But it doesn't, thanks

Comment: @ShaneG It could, but not the way you used it . You can use your last example, and parseFloat the `this.graphicState[i]....` of the right side .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert any/all string values to numbers in an expression that has strings as operands with `+` as the operator. The `5` isn't the issue, this is:

```
this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x
```

So, that's what needs to be converted. You can do that easily by prepending a `+` to it:

```
+this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x;
```

Do the conversion on the string first and then use the converted value in your mathematical expression. Here's a simplified example:

```js
var result = "5"
result = +result + 10;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. Used it before with d3.js. Brilliant thanks for your help.

Comment: withe leading plus, the assignment does not work. `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: @ShaneG You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as the answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz Updated to reflect this.

Comment: Yes it is not working with +this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x += 5

Comment: @ShaneG See updated answer that shows that `+=` should be avoided if the conversion is done in the same expression as the math.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes I see now, and this is working this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x = +this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x + 5 thanks for your help

Comment: I will have to delete the question it is a duplicate, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```js
this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x = (parseFloat(this.graphicState[i].shapes[j][k].x) + 5).toFixed(2);
```