# Issue with checking if an input value is equal to a value in an array

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get this code to work (namely, getting `isInArray(userZipCode,chicagoZipCodes)` to return `true`.

```
  var chicagoZipCodes = [ 60018, 60068, 60176, 60601, 60602, 60603, 60604, 60605, 60606, 60607, 60608, 60609,
                          60610, 60611, 60612, 60613, 60614, 60615, 60616, 60617, 60618, 60619, 60620, 60621,
                          60622, 60623, 60624, 60625, 60626, 60628, 60630, 60631, 60632, 60634, 60636, 60637,
                          60639, 60640, 60641, 60642, 60643, 60644, 60645, 60646, 60647, 60649, 60651, 60652,
                          60653, 60654, 60655, 60656, 60657, 60659, 60660, 60661, 60706, 60707, 60714 ]

  function isInArray(value, array) {
    return array.indexOf(value) !== -1
  }

  elem.bind('change', function(e) {
    userZipCode = $('#zipCode').val();

    alert(isInArray(userZipCode,chicagoZipCodes));

    if ( !(isInArray(userZipCode, chicagoZipCodes)) && (userZipCode.length > 4) ) {
      // success
      alert("Sorry, that is not a Chicago area zip code! :(");
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers guys! Looks like `parseInt` was what I was looking for -- quick and simple solution

Comment: Just note that care should be taken when using `parseInt`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look like you compare numbers and strings

```
function isInArray(value, array) { 
        return array.indexOf(parseInt(value,10)) !== -1 
 }
```

Comment: To add context to this answer, I edited the question to include `return` in `isInArray` but the answer was adding `parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

Parse your $('#zipCode').val() before using the indexOf() function.

```
return array.indexOf(parseInt(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

All values returned from the DOM are strings so you need to convert them to a number. You can do this a few ways but the most direct is to use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) as a function rather than a constructor.

```
 var chicagoZipCodes = [60018, 60068, 60176, 60601, 60602, 60603, 60604, 60605, 60606, 60607, 60608, 60609,
   60610, 60611, 60612, 60613, 60614, 60615, 60616, 60617, 60618, 60619, 60620, 60621,
   60622, 60623, 60624, 60625, 60626, 60628, 60630, 60631, 60632, 60634, 60636, 60637,
   60639, 60640, 60641, 60642, 60643, 60644, 60645, 60646, 60647, 60649, 60651, 60652,
   60653, 60654, 60655, 60656, 60657, 60659, 60660, 60661, 60706, 60707, 60714
 ]

 function isInArray(value, array) {
   return array.indexOf(value) !== -1
 }

 elem.bind('change', function(e) {
   // All values returned from the DOM are strings
   // so we need to convert them to a number
   userZipCode = Number($('#zipCode').val());

   alert(isInArray(userZipCode, chicagoZipCodes));

   // Check length first since all Chicago zips listed are greater than 4 digits
   // Saves the more expensive check of searching the array for
   //   only zips that are greater than 4
   if ((userZipCode.length > 4) && !(isInArray(userZipCode, chicagoZipCodes))) {
     // success
     alert("Sorry, that is not a Chicago area zip code! :(");
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   }
 });
```