# Why isn't this meter working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meter

So I have this code ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBUmQ/239/)):

```js
(function() {
  var meter = document.getElementById('somemeter');
  var Likes = document.getElementById('likes');
  var Dislikes = document.getElementById('dislikes');

  meter.max = Likes.innerHTML + Dislikes.innerHTML;
  meter.value = Likes.innerHTML - Dislikes.innerHTML;
})();
```

```html
<div id="likes">500</div>
<div id="dislikes">50</div>
<meter value="10" min="0" max="1000" id="somemeter"></meter>
```

As you can see, `Likes.innerHTML`is `500` , and `Dislikes.innerHTML` is  `50`

For some reason, the `meter.max` doesn't work when I use `Likes.innerHTML` or `Dislikes.innerHTML`; however, when I substitute those in the `meter.max` for `500` and `50`, it does work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript detect string, you should use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) values, try this code:

```js
(function() {
  var meter = document.getElementById('somemeter');
  var Likes = document.getElementById('likes');
  var Dislikes = document.getElementById('dislikes');

  meter.max = parseInt(Likes.innerHTML) + parseInt(Dislikes.innerHTML);
  meter.value = parseInt(Likes.innerHTML) - parseInt(Dislikes.innerHTML);
  
  console.log(meter.max)
})();
```

```html
<div id="likes">500</div>
<div id="dislikes">50</div>
<meter value="10" min="0" max="1000" id="somemeter"></meter>
```

Comment: Would using parseInt() be better than using Number()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/what-is-the-difference-between-parseint-and-number

Answer (score 3):

Your code is taking the `innerHTML` as string. Use parseInt instead:

```js
(function() {
  var meter = document.getElementById('somemeter');
  var Likes = document.getElementById('likes');
  var Dislikes = document.getElementById('dislikes');

  meter.max = parseInt(Likes.innerHTML, 10) + parseInt(Dislikes.innerHTML, 10);
  meter.value = parseInt(Likes.innerHTML, 10) - parseInt(Dislikes.innerHTML, 10);
})();
```

```html
<div id="likes">500</div>
<div id="dislikes">50</div>
<meter value="10" min="0" max="1000" id="somemeter"></meter>
```

Comment: Would using parseInt() be better than using Number()?

Comment: @ChizbeJoe `Number` is perfectly fine. Just consider how you may handle non numeric values. Aside: the reason why I put the radix (10) is because not including it lets the browser / platform choose radix. See [parseInt at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings to numeric values for the math to work:

```
(function() {
  var meter = document.getElementById('somemeter');
  var Likes = document.getElementById('likes');
  var Dislikes = document.getElementById('dislikes');

  meter.max = Number(Likes.innerHTML) + Number(Dislikes.innerHTML);
  meter.value = Number(Likes.innerHTML) - Number(Dislikes.innerHTML);
})();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBUmQ/241/)

Comment: Thanks dude! I assumed it would work the other way because meter.value worked when I did it the other way.