# Looking for a one line casting Number(oldValue) += 1; in JS

Tags: javascript, casting, numbers, concatenation

I'm creating totals for a row in a table with JavaScript. The cell values are typed as strings, so a += would concatenate a delta. Is there anything that lets me cast this value in one line, so I can still use += without saving the old value in a `old = Number(value)` in an extra lin of code?

```
row.totals.value += delta;
[string]            [Integer]
```

Comment: `row.total.value = +row.total.value + delta;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain you can +=, but you should be able to use this on one line:

```
row.totals.value = Number(rows.totals.value) + delta;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it won't be possible to do it without a casting of the LHS in conjunction with `+=`.

You'd also probably want to be using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` rather than `Number()`. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090577/31671).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

```js
let str = '123';
str = +str + 4;
console.log(str);
```