# Replace JSON array quotes with brackets [

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array being passed form PHP and it looks like this:

```
[{from: "2019,09,14", to: "2019,09,14"}]
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
[{from: [2019, 9, 14], to: [2019, 9, 17]}]
```

here is my code thus far:

function getPricingDateRanges() {
    var city = document.getElementById("pricingcityselect").value;

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getpricingdaterangepicker.php?city=' + city,       // Change this to the uri of your file
    method: 'GET',                 // Use the GET method
    dataType: 'json',              // Expect a JSON response
    success: function(response) {  // What will happen when the request succeeds

        var darray = [{from:[2019,9,14], to:[2019,9,17]}];

        console.log(response);
        console.log(darray);

    }
});
```

}

Added code from my PHP:

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$city = ($_GET['city']);

$sql="SELECT start_date, end_date FROM date_ranges WHERE city='" . $city . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

// Create empty array.
$date_ranges = array();

// Add every row to array;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // Create an associative array to store the values in.
    // This will later be a JavaScript Object.

    $from = new DateTime($row['start_date']);
    $ffrom = $from->format('Y,m,d');

    $to = new DateTime($row['end_date']);
    $fto = $from->format('Y,m,d');

    array_push($date_ranges, array(
        'from'   => $ffrom,
        'to'     => $fto
    ));

} 

// Send the $date_ranges as JSON.
$json = json_encode($date_ranges); // '[{"start": "2019-08-18", "end": "2019-08-19"}]'
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: `[{from: "2019,09,14", to: "2019,09,14"}]` is not JSON. Can you please clarify what `response` is in your code?

Comment: added code, is my php wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First, it's important to point out that the "JSON" you've included is *not* JSON. It is neither a string, nor are the property names quoted.

However, if this is actually the input you're dealing with, you can loop through the items, split the `from` and `to` values on `,`, and use `.map(Number)` to convert them to integers.

```js
const arr = [{from: "2019,09,14", to: "2019,09,14"}];
 
//Helper function to split on comma, convert items to numbers
const toIntegerArray = str => str.split(",").map(Number);

const result = arr.map(({from,to}) => ({
  from: toIntegerArray(from),
  to: toIntegerArray(to)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looks nice. Just curious, when can we substitute `el => parseInt(el)` by expected type `Number`?

Comment: Thanks Alex. You can read about the differences (better than I could explain) here: [What is the difference between parseInt() and Number()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/what-is-the-difference-between-parseint-and-number) In this case, `.map(Number)` is just shorthand for `.map(el => Number(el))`.

Comment: Yes, I  got it. In this case we use Number as constructor function, that accepts string and returns number. Therefore it fits to callback declaration. Thanks!

Comment: While this works, and has the same console output as the other array, it is not working with my the date picker I am using.

Comment: You'll have to clarify. Your question said *"I have input that looks like A and I want it to look like B"*, so that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Parse `JSON` till the point with `"2019,09,14"`.

then `"2019,09,14"` convert to array of numbers by:

```
"2019,09,14".split(',').map(el => parseInt(el, 10))
```

Comment: You might want to add a `10` [_radix_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) parameter to `parseInt`, otherwise the zero-padded numbers might be interpreted as octal