# How to filter typescript array based on a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to filter an array in TypeScript but using a variable instead of a hardcoded number. Most of the results on Stack Overflow talk about filtering arrays with arrays but none talk about using a single variable.

I have an array of objects of this type:

```
class pair {
    name: string,
    value: number
}
```

and I want to create a function that filters some of these out based on a value.

```
myFunction(removeMe: string) {
    ...
    var resultingArray = arrayOfPairObjects.filter(x => x.value === Number(removeMe)); // the cast is necessary, sadly
    return resultingArray;
}
```

But if I do this, `removeMe` is set properly however *its value becomes undefined* when the filter runs. I have no idea why, but if I change `Number(removeMe)` to `2` it works perfectly. I just need to know how to make the variable work.

Thank you!

EDIT: By becomes undefined, I mean that I can log the removeMe value on the console on the line immediately before the .filter() and its value is correct (is ‘1’ or ‘2’, whatever is passed in), but I get an error in the console saying that the value within the .filter() is undefined. I think it’s maybe losing scope but I’m a bit new to Typescript so maybe there’s a subtlety I’m not aware of.

Comment: What do you mean by "becomes undefined"? Where are you seeing the undefined value?

Comment: what does `removeMe` look like as a string?

Comment: We need to see how you call `myFunction`. Can you make a stackblitz?

Comment: maybe use parseInt instead of Number (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/what-is-the-difference-between-parseint-and-number)

Comment: @richytong removeMe contains a number but it is of type String due to some other constraints. ie. ‘1’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayOfPairObjects: Pair[] = [
  { name: 'hello', value: 2 },
  { name: 'hello', value: 5 },
  { name: 'hello', value: 7 },
  { name: 'hello', value: 8 },
  { name: 'hello', value: 9 },
  { name: 'hello', value: 10 }
]

// removeMe is a little bit confusing, but okay..
getFilteredArray(removeMe: string) {
   return this.arrayOfPairObjects.filter(x => x.value === +removeMe); 
}

console.log(this.getFilteredArray('7'));

// Output:  
// { name: 'hello', value: 7 }
```

Comment: Sorry, by removeMe I mean I’d like the original array with value 7 removed. Can probably change the condition to check for !== that though, thank you.