# Difference between Number and Integer in Javascript(I thought Integers exist because of parseInt)

Tags: javascript, numbers, integer

What is the difference between a Number and Integer in Javascript. This is an edit after the answer - I thought that the Integer datatype exists because of the function parseInt.

Comment: `Number` exists, "integer" doesn't…?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/

Comment: Oh ok. But why is my question showing closed? I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @AkashShyam Because your question doesn't make much sense. You are comparing an existing datatype with a non existing datatype. You could at least explain why you believe both exist. Or what is causing your confusion. You can also read through [ask] on how you can ask good questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ivar could you please remove the negative vote as I am unable to ask new questions due to a question ban

Comment: Is there any code involved that could provide more insights? What exactly do you mean by "Number" or "Integer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Integer` type in JavaScript; it treats ints and floats the same way