# How do I create a controlled component with an optional value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, controlled-component

In React, I'm trying to create a form in which some values are optional.  I have the following TypeScript interface:

```
export interface DataModel {
    title:      string,
    count?:     number,
}
```

`count` is optional, but if it's set, it has to be a number.

I've set up my initial object like this:

```
const INITIAL_VALUE = {
  title: "",
  count: undefined
}

const dataItem = useState(INITIAL_VALUE);
```

Then I create a form:

```
<form onSubmit = { handleSave }>
  <input
    name     = "title"
    value    = { dataItem.title}
    onChange = { handleChange }
    type     = "text"
    placeholder = "Enter title"
  />
  <input
    name        = "count"
    value       = { dataItem.count}
    onChange    = { handleChange }
    type        = "number"
  />
</form>
```

So the `count` input is initially getting a value of `undefined`, but then when I enter a value, I get the error:

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled

I can avoid this by initializing it with a value, but as it's optional I don't want to do that. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a proper initial value. And, that could be `0` or empty string - `""`. Empty string should be fine even when **input type** is `number`. Because `e.target.value` is always *string*.

If you want to store it as a *number*, turn the value to number using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) (check details to make sure they [fit the need](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090518/2873538)) in your event handler or do this before making payload for the API call.

Hence, you should simply define the interface and initial values as:

```
export interface DataModel {
  title: string;
  count: number | ""; // count is a number or empty string
}

const INITIAL_VALUE = {
  title: "",
  count: "",
};
```

This way the component always stays as a controlled component.

Comment: One can also use [`e.target.valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). Note that its value is `NaN` when you enter something like `123XYZ` (similar to `Number("123XYZ")`).

Comment: Sorry, I've been working on other things this week and haven't had a chance to get back to this until today!

Answer (score 2):

When you define the value property of a component to be undefined, it essentially means that the component is an uncontrolled component. However if in the next cycle you have a value property, the behaviour of the component changes from unControlled to controlled.

To solve this, you can add a default value for your inputs

```
<form onSubmit = { handleSave }>
  <input
    name     = "title"
    value    = { dataItem.title || ''}
    onChange = { handleChange }
    type     = "text"
    placeholder = "Enter title"
  />
  <input
    name        = "count"
    value       = { dataItem.count || 0}
    onChange    = { handleChange }
    type        = "number"
  />
</form>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `??` be *better* here?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes that can be used as well here

Comment: The problem is that there isn't really a default value I can use.  0 could mean that 'count' is 0, but it could mean that it hasn't been set.  I need to be able to distinguish between those two options.

Comment: If that is your case, you can ignore the warning, It doesn't actually affect the working of your code