# Value not incemented by one?

Tags: node.js, react-hooks, formik

I have created a survey form with formik in react hooks. Initial state values of react variables are fetched by the database. I have created an icon button that increments the value of votes by one onclick. The problem is whenever I have clicked on icon value not incremented by.

[Initial state before clicking on icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdoZX.png)

[result after clicking on icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sxxN.png)

I have attached the above screenshot of the output before and after a click on the button.

Code:

```
// @ts-ignore

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import {
  Typography,
  Button,
  Grid,
  CircularProgress,
  Divider,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { MyInput } from './comman/MyInput';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Event } from '../Tracking/Event';
import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt';
import Unsubscribed from './Unsubscribed';

const contactSchema = Yup.object().shape({});
export default function SurveyUnsubscribed(props: any) {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [countone, setCountOne] = useState(0);
  const [counttwo, setCountTwo] = useState(0);
  const [countthree, setCountThree] = useState(0);
 
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    msg: '',
  });

  async function getInitialValues() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_DEVELOPMENT_VOTING_API_GET}`,
      );
      var voteone = response.data.map(function (obj: any) {
        console.log('value',parseInt(obj.voteone))
        return parseInt(obj.voteone);
      });
      var votetwo = response.data.map(function (obj: any) {
        return obj.votetwo;
      });
      var votethree = response.data.map(function (obj: any) {
        return obj.votethree;
      });
      var votefour = response.data.map(function (obj: any) {
        return obj.votefour;
      });
      return {
        voteone,
        votetwo,
        votethree,
        votefour,
        helptext: '',
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCount(res.voteone));
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountOne(res.votetwo));
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountTwo(res.votethree));
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountThree(res.votefour));
 
 
  }, []);

   return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        initialValues={{
          count: count,
          countone: countone,
          counttwo: counttwo,
          countthree: countthree,
          helptext: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={contactSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
          setLoading(true);

          const data = {
            count: values.count,
            countone: values.countone,
            counttwo: values.counttwo,
            countthree: values.countthree,
            helptext: values.helptext,
          };
          const request = new Request(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_DEVELOPMENT_VOTING_API}`,
            {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }),
              body: JSON.stringify(data),
            },
          );

          fetch(request)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              if (data.message === 'Thank you for your feedback!') {
                setState({
                  msg: data.message,
                });
                setIsSubmitted(true);
                setTimeout(() => {
                  setLoading(false);
                }, 1500);
              } else {
                console.log('error');
              }
            });
          setTimeout(() => {
            setIsSubmitted(false);
          }, 1500);

          resetForm();
        }}
      >
        {({ setFieldValue }) => (
          <Grid container>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={12}
              style={{ paddingLeft: '2em', paddingRight: '2em' }}
            >
              {isSubmitted}
              <Form>
                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field
                    type="hidden"
                    name="count"
                    component={ThumbUpAltIcon}
                    onClick={() => setCount( count + 1 )}
                    style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}
                  />
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {count}
                  </Typography>
                  Complaince and Tax Return Filing Dates.
                </Typography>

                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field
                    type="hidden"
                    name="countone"
                    component={ThumbUpAltIcon}
                    onClick={() => setCountOne( countone + 1 )}
                    style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}
                  />
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {countone}
                  </Typography>
                  Excel Sheet for Calculation of GSTR 3B.
                </Typography>

                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field
                    type="hidden"
                    name="counttwo"
                    component={ThumbUpAltIcon}
                    onClick={() => setCountTwo( counttwo + 1 )}
                    style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}
                  />
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {counttwo}
                  </Typography>
                  Excel Sheet for GSTR 2A vs ITC Books matching.
                </Typography>

                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field
                    type="hidden"
                    name="countthree"
                    component={ThumbUpAltIcon}
                    onClick={() => setCountThree(countthree + 1)}
                    style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}
                  />
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {countthree}
                  </Typography>
                  Details of applicable law on directors and requirement of
                  Director KYC.
                </Typography>

                <br />
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: '2em',
                    marginTop: '0.5em',
                  }}
                >
                  What information would help you ?
                </Typography>
                <Field
                  id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
                  type="text"
                  name="helptext"
                  component={MyInput}
                  disabled={isSubmitted}
                  style={{ marginLeft: '2em' }}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                  style={{
                    background: '#2F4858',
                    color: 'white',
                    fontFamily: 'roboto',
                    fontSize: '1rem',
                    marginLeft: '2em',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  {loading && (
                    <CircularProgress
                      size={25}
                      color="inherit"
                      style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}
                    />
                  )}
                  {loading && <span>submitting</span>}
                  {!loading && <span>Submit</span>}
                </Button>
                <br />
                {state.msg && (
                  <Typography
                    variant="h6"
                    style={{
                      color: '#4BB543',
                      fontFamily: 'roboto-medium',
                      marginTop: '1em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {' '}
                    {state.msg}{' '}
                  </Typography>
                )}
              </Form>
              <Divider
                style={{
                  border: '1px solid #97A1A8',
                  marginTop: '1em',
                  marginBottom: '2em',
                }}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}


Whenever I have clicked on the thumbs-up icon value is incremented by one but value 1 is inserted in front of the previous one. I want to increment value by one. ( 1 increment by 2 ).
```

Thanks In advance guys.

Comment: What is the `console.log('value', Number.parseInt(obj.voteone));` gives you?

Comment: gives output 1 but whenever clicked on button value incremented by 11, not 2.

Comment: Yeah, So that's a string, you will need to parse it to Number first.

Comment: please suggest me any built-in function that converts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **It's the nature of javascript when you add a string to a number**

```js
console.log(1+"1") // <-- Gives "11"
console.log(1+1)  // <-- Gives "2"
```

Your first `count` is fine, but when you get a response from the API, your `res.voteone` is definitely a string.

**So you will need to parse your response to a number first:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCount(Number(res.voteone)));
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountOne(Number(res.votetwo)));
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountTwo(Number(res.votethree)));
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountThree(Number(es.votefour)));
}, []);
```

**OR**

```
useEffect(() => {
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCount(parseInt(res.voteone)));
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountOne(parseInt(res.votetwo)));
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountTwo(parseInt(res.votethree)));
  getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountThree(parseInt(es.votefour)));
}, []);
```

---

`Number()` and `parseInt()` [behaves a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/what-is-the-difference-between-parseint-and-number) but in your case it's not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of type coercion. As in, in javasript `"1"+1` gives `11`. To fix, you should convert the results from response to number.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCount(Number(res.voteone)));
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountOne(Number(res.votetwo)));
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountTwo(Number(res.votethree)));
    getInitialValues().then((res: any) => setCountThree(Number(res.votefour)));
 }, []);
```

Comment: please suggest any example.

Comment: In the code I posted. `setCount(Number(res.voteone))` note that I wrapped the res.voteone in Number that converts the value to a number