# JDBC Select Query multi table

Tags: java, jquery, database, jdbc

address

| addrId | street |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Berkeley |
| 0 | Berkeley |

name

| addrId | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Fred Jam |
| 1 | Bread Mi |

```
...
String sql = "select * from address, name";

statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(sql);

...
```

when this code execute, occur Error

Error Message is

```
"java.sql.SQLException: Cannot invoke "[Ljava.lang.String;.clone()" because "columnNames" is null"
```

I want to play "select * from join table"

What do i do?

Help me please.

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS let's use jQuery! :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811678/add-two-variables-using-jquery

Comment: Hi , you need to specify columns which you need to fetch from both  tables .